# ESP32 esp-idf what is the sdkconfig.ci file used for?

Tags: esp32, esp-idf

Several of the examples in the esp-idf contain a `sdkconfig.ci` file (e.g. [examples/bluetooth/nimble/blehr](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/master/examples/bluetooth/nimble/blehr)).

I understand the usage of `sdkconfig.defaults` but I can't find any reference to `sdkconfig.ci` in the Espressif [build system API guide](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/build-system.html).

When should the `.ci` file be used and under what conditions are the configurations in it applied?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sdkconfig.ci are configs used when building apps in their own CI system, so these by default won't do anything in your project.

Usually, we can set config values using menuconfig, and these will be saved to sdkconfig. If there is a need to set some default values ( without using menuconfig), then this is possible by adding a sdkconfig.default file, and then add the new options there.

Comment: Thanks - I don't know what a CI system is but I understand that the settings in sdkconfig.ci will not do anything in a 'normal' project. It's a bit confusing to include them in the sdk examples without an explanation so I'll do a PR to add an explanatory comment.

Comment: CI = [Continuous Integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration).

Answer (score 2):

The documentation (https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/build-system.html?highlight=default%20component) has been updated, and now it mentions **sdkconfig.ci** file.

"Some of the IDF examples include a sdkconfig.ci file. This is part of the continuous integration (CI) test framework and is ignored by the normal build process."

Comment: Yes, that was my PR